# Ngrx selector return error cannot read property (reading 'payload')

Tags: angular

Hello I created this NGRX selector

```
 import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
 import { AppState } from '../app.states';
 import { CustomerState } from './customer.reducer';

 export const appSelectCustomer = (state: AppState) => state.customerstate;

export const selectCustomer = createSelector(
    appSelectCustomer,
  (state) => state.payload 
);


export const selectCustomerIsLoading = createSelector(
  appSelectCustomer,
  (state: CustomerState) => state.loading
);
```

In my store, the data come successfully but when I call the selector  in my component I have this issue:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'payload')

```
     ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select(selectCustomer).subscribe((res) => {this.data = res});
  }
```

Comment: Try changing this `(state) => state.payload` to this `(state) => state?.payload`.

Comment: thanks this (state) => state?.payload  has solved the problem but the result is still empty

Comment: Can you share your reducer code?

Comment: Thank you I solved it.  the problem was in my core module in the name of the reducer StoreModule.forFeature('customer', CustomerReducer),